# PowerShell get-aduser email with apostrophe

Tags: powershell

AD user has an apostrophe in the email address - First.O'Last@email.com
PowerShell commands:

```
$email = "First.O'Last@email.com"
Get-ADUser -Filter "(EmailAddress -eq '$($email)')"
```

- doesn't work.

```
$email = "First.Last@email.com"
Get-ADUser -Filter "(EmailAddress -eq '$($email)')"
```

- works.

How do I make the command work if there is an apostrophe in the email?

Comment: You need to escape the `'`. You can just use `''` (double single-quotes) in the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a quote style to surround a string value, inner like-quotes need to be escaped. One way to do this is doubling the quote.

```
# Notice the two consecutive single quotes
$email = "First.O''Last@email.com" 
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$email'"
```

Note that you only need the double `'` because your `EmailAddress` attribute value contains the surrounding `'` in the filter, which is a great practice for this filter. Using outer double quotes for the filter and inner single quotes for the attribute value is best practice.

---

However, since you are storing your search value in a variable that can be retrieved by expandable string, you can simplify your example by surrounding the entire filter in single quotes removing the need for the inner quoting.

```
$email = "First.O'Last@email.com"
Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -eq $email'
```

---

Typically, you may have a list of attributes to query from a file or other object. Let's say for example that you have a list of email addresses in a CSV file called `users.csv`. The emails are in a column called `email`. You can programmatically replace single quotes with two single quotes before running your `Get-ADUser` command:

```
$users = Import-Csv users.csv
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $email = $user.email -replace "'","''"
    Get-ADUser -filter "mail -eq '$email'"
}
```

Comment: The task I have is to read user properties from AD, and the user's email is one of the most important and can't be changed. The solution you gave me is what I need: Get-ADUser -Filter 'EmailAddress -eq $email' . Thank you very much.